# Is "cover one's fee" a formal structure?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I was wondering if "cover one's living fee" can be included in a TOEFL essay.

My teacher thought the structure was not formal enough, but she does not know how to replace it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say when you say "living fee". Do you mean costs such as accommodation, food etc? In that case "cover cost of living" may be better.

Comment: To the extent of the basic question, no, “(to) cover one's (living) fee” is not a recognized "formal structure" in English language usage as far as I know. However, one might very well say "cover one's **living expenses and** (tuition) fees"

Comment: Possibly a translation error. What has been translated as *fee* might also be *cost,* and "cover one's living costs" would work (although "cover the cost of living" is probably more idiomatic).

Answer (score 3):

*Cover*, meaning to pay for, is common enough in the expression *to cover a fee*. A fee is charge for a particular service, and if it's covered, someone's paid for it. For example, your health insurance might **cover a fee** for a second opinion. But, the word *fee* isn't applied to living. You're likely thinking of *living expenses*, which, of course, can be covered.

Comment: To expand a little on this answer: a *fee* suggests a specific cost for a specific purpose, usually in exchange for services or privileges rather than concrete items.  But there’s no single specific fee for living — the costs referred to are a large variety of different costs, hence should be referred to as *living costs* or *living expenses*, as the answer suggests.  (One could imagine, though, in a dystopian novel, an authoritarian government might charge its citizens a *living fee*, with those who can’t or won’t pay being executed…)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to express it in a very formal way, you can also use this legal term: 'to perform the payment of one's expenses'.